# Pandas: advanced processing within groups

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am doing some stock portfolio statistics. In particular I have a transaction log with several buy and sell orders which I group by stock. This gives such a grouping for AAPL for example:

```
    Date        Form        Amount     Price
0   2013-12-01  IN          10          10
1   2013-12-02  IN          10          5
2   2013-05-01  OUT         10          7
```

Is there any possibility that I can calculate for this group the cumulative amount and average buying price for the second and thrid line. So that I get the following result.

```
    Date                Cum_Amount  Avg_Buy_Price
0   2013-12-01          10          10
1   2013-12-02          20          7.5
2   2013-05-01          10          7.5
```

I appreciate any help.

Thanks

**Update**

Unfortunately the 'expanding_mean' function as proposed by joris as the the Avg_Buy_Price needs to be weighted by the corresponding Amount of the IN transaction.

Comment: How have you got the third line?

Comment: Hi Andy, the thrid line is the OUT transaction, where 10 pices are subtracted from the existing Cum_Amount. Also this OUT transaction does not affect the Avg_Buy_Price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like the following (I made up another stock to make it clear what it does):

```
print df

  Ticker        Date Form  Amount  Price
0   AAPL  2013-12-01   IN      10     10
1   AAPL  2013-12-02   IN      10      5
2   AAPL  2014-01-05  OUT      10      7
3    KKD  2013-12-22   IN      20     30
4    KKD  2013-12-29   IN      20     35
5    KKD  2014-01-15  OUT       5     40
6    KKD  2013-01-22  OUT       5     45

def cum_amount(x):
    x.ix[x['Form'] == 'OUT','Amount'] =  -x.ix[x['Form'] == 'OUT','Amount'] 
    return pd.DataFrame(pd.expanding_sum(x.Amount))

def weighted_avg(g):
    x = g[g['Form'] == 'IN']
    avg = pd.expanding_sum(x.Amount*x.Price)/pd.expanding_sum(x.Amount)
    g['avg'] = avg
    return g[['avg']]

df['Cum_Amount'] = df.groupby('Ticker').apply(cum_amount)
df['Avg_BuyPrice'] = df.groupby('Ticker').apply(weighted_avg)
print df

 Ticker        Date Form  Amount  Price  Cum_Amount  Avg_BuyPrice
0   AAPL  2013-12-01   IN      10     10          10          10.0
1   AAPL  2013-12-02   IN      10      5          20           7.5
2   AAPL  2014-01-05  OUT      10      7          10           NaN
3    KKD  2013-12-22   IN      20     30          20          30.0
4    KKD  2013-12-29   IN      20     35          40          32.5
5    KKD  2014-01-15  OUT       5     40          35           NaN
6    KKD  2013-01-22  OUT       5     45          30           NaN
```

And just fill forward the missing values for Avg_BuyPrice if you want

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot. I pretty much like the idea how you use the expanding_sum function.